# I want to get the latest file names under each directory of gcs

Tags: bash, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I want to know the path to the latest file under each directory using gsutil ls.

Executing the command in a loop like this is very slow.

I want the final output to be

How can I do this?

I want to know the path to the latest file under each directory using gsutil ls.

shell script

```
for dir in dir_list[@];do
  file+=$(gsutil ls -R ${dir} | tail -n 1);
done
```

Running the command in a loop process is very slow.

I want the final output to be

Is there another way?

results image

```
gs://bucket/dir_a/latest.txt
gs://bucket/dir_b/latest.txt
gs://bucket/dir_c/latest.txt
gs://bucket/dir_d/latest.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't other strategy for a good reason: directory doesn't exist. So, you need to scan all the files, get the metadata, get this one which is the last, and do that for each "similar prefix".

A prefix is what you call directories "/path/to/prefix/". That's why you can only perform search by prefix in GCS not by file pattern.

So, you can imagine to build a custom app which, for each different prefix (directory), create a concurrent process (fork) dedicated to this prefix. Like that you can perform parallelization. It's not so simple to write but you can!